# Compute effect size from simulated NULL distribution

Tags: p-value, effect-size, permutation-test

I computed a empirical p-value (permutation test) where I compare my real value to simulated values (N=100,000). In the end I've a distribution like this (vertical line = my real value). For the p-value I count the number of simulated value higher or equal than my real value ; and divide by the number of simulated values (N=100,000). Then to have some kind of effect size idea, is it possible to compute it from the null distribution. Something like `real_value - mean(simulated_values)` ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by effect size?

Comment: some kind of foldchange between the null distribution and the real value.

Comment: Your p-value distribution looks quite normal, so your formula with the mean will work.